# How i can receive next or previous element in arango collection?

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-php

I have a document in ArangoDB.
I need to receive the previous document.
How can I receive the previous document in the Arango collection?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *previous* or *next* document? Do you mean the temporally previous or next documents inserted or updated in the same collection?

Comment: If you're only after accessing documents first inserted or last inserted, the commands `db.collection.first()` or `db.collection.last()` might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

My Way is:

```
FOR d IN MyCollection
    FILTER TO_NUMBER(d._key) < 512989295537
    SORT d._key DESC LIMIT 1
    RETURN d._key
```

But, I think it is not optimal...

Comment: That query will do a full scan of the collection and not use any indexes. If you could store some additional value on insert in another attribute (e.g. `counter`, which will always be increasing), then you could skiplist-index that attribute and run the query on it. That would also be efficient as that could use an index then.